# Accessing class properties inside the class via the this.PropertyGet

Tags: c#, matrix

I'm building a C# class for matrices. I actually found something on SO to get started with so I don't have to start from scratch. The guy's class has a private property for the rows and columns of the matrix and a `get()` and `set()` property. Sometimes the guy refers to the properties themselves by name `mRowCount` and `mColumnCount` or by the `this.RowCount` and `this.ColumnCount` inside the class for calculation purposes as seen below (I only added relevant code):

```
public class Matrix
{
  private decimal[,] mInnerMatrix;
  private int mRowCount, mColumnCount = 0;

  public int RowCount
  {
    get { return mRowCount; }
  }
  public int ColumnCount
  {
    get { return mColumnCount; }
  }
}
```

Sometimes in the code the guy uses the properties by name `mRowCount` and `mColumnCount` and other times using `this.RowCount` and `this.ColumnCount` instead of the former way. What is the difference? Is one way better and if so with respects to what? Particularly in boolean methods where the methods checks to see if the object/matrix is a diagonal, symmetric or square matrix the developer uses the `this.RowCount` and `this.ColumnCount` in the loops that run through the `mInnerMatrix[]` array that holds the matrix's data. Other times he uses the properties themselves. Can anyone explain why someone  might do this or is it a mistake? What should I use and should I use it throughout the entire program?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the `get` and `set` methods can be not that straightforward. For instance if you don't store rows and cols count but instead store rows and total elements, you would have to divide total by rows to get cols:

```
public Cols {get {return _mTotal/_mRows;}}
```

This is not the best sample, but you can get the idea. In your simple case there will be no difference whether to use a field or a property (if you actually have `set` methods but omitted them, otherwise the properties are readonly!). But note that one day you might want to implement some logic in `get`. Then the code that's using properties would work fine but the code that's using fields would fail.

Outside a class you always have to use properties, if any. In fact, you would declare fields `private` so that only within the class you can access them. Technically you can use both fields and properties outside class, but that would lead to a chaos.

On the other hand I would disagree that mixing properties and fields access within a class is always discouraged. Sometimes you would really need this access, the easiest sample is when your property is readonly (has only `get`).

Comment: "On the other hand I would disagree that mixing properties and fields access within a class is always discouraged." - and can you give some examples where mixing access is good? Example with get is not example at all, as i mentioned "use them wherever possible", with read-only property, that, in fact, is not possible

Comment: Okay, what if your `get` logic requires complex synchronisation, but within some method you are already synchronised and thus can access the member directly? What if your `get` updates data from a database while you in a method have just updated the entire object and don't need more recent data? What if your `set` updates data in a database while you (in lock) want to update all the object at once? And many many other samples.

Comment: "What if your set updates data in a database while you (in lock) want to update all the object at once?" than I have bad news for you - that means a big problem in OO design and using direct member access to work around that leads to even worse situation...Using direct access in cases where property access is not possible or property access produce some side effects usually means troubles and complete mess

Comment: Technically one can create one property per each field and then fulfill your suggestion. Thus I can not show a scenario where it is required to use fields. But for conviency you may use it but only if you know what you're doing.  As of the example, it is not the best, sure. You would normally use something like `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` in that case, but if you do not want to allow users to suspend updating till `EndUpdate` and use it only internally, I'd say it's not bad to use a field directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined properties - use them wherever possible, inside or outside class, as they may contain additional logic, not only direct member access.

One valid reason not to use properties (use direct access instead) - in constructor, 
every other access should be made using properties.

It's rather bad practice to mix direct access and properties within a class